# Extend Kafka Connect SinkTask and start consuming from given offsets

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to extend `SinkTask` to create my own sink connector.

If I save the offsets during the flush, and the next time I start the sink connector I would like to resume reading from my saved offsets, what would be the correct way to do it?

I tried using the `SinkTaskContext` of the overridden `initialize(SinkTaskContext context)` to assign my own offsets:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(SinkTaskContext context) {
  HashMap<TopicPartition, Long> offsetMap = new HashMap<>();
  ...
  context.offset(offsetMap);
}
```

But this doesn’t work, because the partitions are not assigned yet. I was getting an exception.

Should I then save the context (from `initialize()`) into a global variable and then use it to assign the offsets to it inside the method `open(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions)` (overridden from `SinkTask`) in the same way I was doing inside `initialize`? e.g.:

```java
@Override
public void open(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
  HashMap<TopicPartition, Long> offsetMapNew = new HashMap<>();
  for (TopicPartition tp : partitions) // for each partition assigned
  {
     Long offset = myOffsetMap.get(tp.topic() + "-" + tp.partition());
     if (offset == null) { offset = 0l; } // 0 Long
     offsetMapNew.put(tp, offset);
  }
  mySavedTaskContext.offset(offsetMapNew); // sync offsets ?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting offsets during `open()` *should* be the correct approach, but due to a [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2894) that's still unresolved, it will not currently be handled properly.

The workaround for now is to handle resetting offsets in `put()`. This may be a bit counterintuitive, but since you're managing your own offsets, you can actually ignore data if you like. When you get the first `put()` call you can handle loading the offsets and resetting them. All subsequent data will be from the offsets you specified when resetting. This is how the [HDFS connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-hdfs) currently implements its exactly once delivery. (That is a good example of how you can get exactly once, but relatively complex code, unfortunately.) In fact, since the HDFS connector was what drove the offset management functionality in Kafka Connect, the fact that it doesn't do the reset on rebalance is precisely how this was missed in the implementation.

Comment: Thank you Ewen. I only wanted to share more details about this question, in our discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/QsgWbXeSGZA)